# Windows-8 lock screen password permanent removal

Tags: windows-8

Is there no way to completely remove lock screen? All of the tutorials for it that I have seen is undone after the computer restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basic instructions:

1. Press Windows-R to open the "Run" dialog.
2. Type "regedit" and press ENTER.
3. Drill down to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization`.
4. Create a new DWORD value called "NoLockScreen".
5. Double-click on the "NoLockScreen" value can enter a value of 1.
6. Close regedit.

I found these instructions on [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/134620/how-to-disable-the-lock-screen-on-windows-8-without-using-group-policy/).

Comment: I have already done that, it just revert back after restart

Comment: From further investigation, it looks like this will only work on a Windows 8 **Pro** installation. Are you running Windows 8 **Home**?